# TCPDF: Rotate Text in cell

Tags: tcpdf

I am trying to rotate text in the cell with TCPDF.

This is what I am expecting to have

[image]

With the following sample code:

```
$pdf->Cell(30, 40, 'Text 1', 1, 0);
$pdf->StartTransform();
$pdf->Rotate(90); 
$pdf->Cell(30, 0, 'Value 1', 1, 0);
$pdf->StopTransform();
$pdf->Cell(30, 40, 'Value 2', 1, 0,'L',0,''); // skipped rotation for testing
$pdf->Cell(30, 40, 'Text 2', 1, 1);
```

I am able to get rotate the cell which gives an output of:

[image]

I would appriciate some pointers on what I could be missing, and how could I achieve only the text rotation with TCPDF.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. You have to take care of the **X and Y** coordinates!

```
        $this->Cell(30, 40, 'Text 1', 1, 0);

        $this->SetY($this->GetY() + 40, false);
        $this->StartTransform();
        $this->Rotate(90);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Value 1', 1, 0);
        $this->StopTransform();
        $this->SetX($this->GetX() - 30);

        $this->StartTransform();
        $this->Rotate(90);
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Value 2', 1, 0);
        $this->StopTransform();
        $this->SetX($this->GetX() - 30);

        $this->SetY($this->GetY() - 40, false);
        $this->Cell(30, 40, 'Text 2', 1, 1);
```

[image]